# DIfference between crypto.X509 and crypto.X509Req in pyOpenSSL

Tags: python-2.7, pyopenssl

The [pyOpenSSL documentation](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/) does not tell much about the difference between `crypto.X509` and `crypto.X509Req` in ***pyOpenSSL***. Examples available on the internet uses both, however I am unable to find a clear difference between the two.

Comment: Like [`X509Req`](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509req-objects) is a signing request object when [`X509`](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509-objects) stands for the certificate itself? By the way they appear as objects in the docs, so can you tell why you notate them with parentheses?

Comment: Removed parentheses. Also, what you said makes sense. Thank you!